# Почему дни — выходные?

Tags: этимология

Интересно, а почему свободные дни называются выходными? Из-за того ли, что только в эти дни можно было выйти куда-то, кроме работы?))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Слово "выходной"(и день, и человек)применялось поначалу  к той категории работников, которые обслуживали дом хозяина и вынуждены были работать и в праздники,и в воскресенье, не выходя с хозяйского двора. Им давали другие дни для выхода, не связанные с общими нерабочими днями, назвав их выходными. Потому и сам работник назывался тоже выходным, а сейчас это значение забылось, в некоторых словарях "выходной" по отношению к человеку считается разговорным,метонимичным. Количество выходных определялось хозяином, могло не соответствовать периодичности 1 раз в неделю,так что от недели слово не зависит. Для всех остальных нерабочими днями были воскресные.Это потом стали называть выходными и все вообще нерабочие дни.

Воскресенье стало выходным (по сути, а не по названию)впервые  ещё 21 марта 321 года , это император Константин Великий объявил воскресенье нерабочим  днем.

В России запрещение пользоваться трудом крепостных по воскресеньям встречается  уже в XVII веке. В 1699 году князь Оболенский был посажен в тюрьму за принуждение своих крестьян работать по воскресеньям
21 сентября 1741 года в регламенте постановлено, что работы должны оканчиваться в субботу в 12 часов дня и совсем прекращаться по воскресеньям.

Манифест о трёхдневной барщине от 5 апреля 1797 года — юридическое запрещение принуждать крестьян к работе в воскресные дни.

Answer (score 6):

Итак, что такое выходной? Английское week-end – просто "конец недели", а польское dzień wolny (джень вольны)– "свободный день". Русское слово выходной (или выходной день), скорее всего, пришло к нам, когда элита российского общества лучше говорила по-французски, нежели по-русски и скопировала французское "de sortie" или jour de sortie (от слова "sortir", обозначающее "выход"). Таким образом, нынешнее русское слово "выходной" этимологически обозначает возможность выхода (в свет).

Именно тогда, вероятнее всего, из русского языка ушло слово «неделя», которое в остальных славянских языках обозначает «воскресенье». Ведь, согласитесь, есть в этом логика: шесть дней трудись, а седьмой – ничего не делай. Вот и получается, что в полном смысле слова выходной для славян – это день ничего неделания. Сравните: украинский (неділя), белорусский (нядзеля), польский (niedziela), чешский (neděle), словацкий (nedeľa), сербский (недеља), хорватский (nedjelja), словенский (nedelja), македонский (недела), болгарский (неделя). Во всех этих языках слово «воскресенье» состоит из отрицательной частички "не" и корня "делать". Вот так и получается, что "дней ничего неделания" у всех один, а у русских – семь. :)

Comment: Супер. А тогда объясните, пожалуйста, почему в русском неделя - это неделя. Получается неделю называли по последнему дню? Ну, а американцы, напротив, начинают неделю с воскресенья и заканчивают субботой.

Comment: Так и на Руси было довольно долго. А церковный календарь и сейчас начинает неделю с воскресенья.

Comment: gecube, потому что наш человек и всю неделю не особо-то перетруждается))))))))

Answer (score 1):

На Руси неделей называли воскресенье,т.е. день когда ничего не делали, а посвящали его Богу.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, уже не смешно. Первоначальный смысл слова "неделя" не ощущается, т.к. словообразовательная модель, по которой оно образовано, не актуальна и к тому же все слова, связанные с деланием, делом, произносятся с твердым л. Скорее уж слышится какое-то (не)деление. Обратите внимание, что даже при явном родстве мы, например, говоря о праздниках, не вспоминаем слова "праздный", "праздность". Потому что они окрашены негативно, а праздник для нас что-то хорошее, связанное не только и не столько с ничегонеделанием, а больше с радостью, торжеством, ликованием. Так жизнь "разводит" родственные слова, наполняя их новым смыслом.

Comment: "Л" не выглядит твердым в словах: дельце, делишки, делец, дельный.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас  в нашем нынешнем языке очень много таких слов ,которые потеряли свой первоначальный смысл и употребляются к совсем противоположным предметам,значениям. Не знаю почему так получилось,может специально кто то нас запутал,умышленно. Интересно,а как же тогда называли дни когда работали. Смешно звучит "рабочая неделя",не правда ли?